# How to implement mouse drivers Linux USB mouse driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I need to control mouse pointer of my computer screen using an external device.I just know i have to write a device driver for that device. It's a usb device.

Can anyone tell me how should i approach this problem ?

What are the modules and algorithms will be required for this?

I ll appreciate if you can provide some reference material?

Sorry for such trivial questions but am a newbie in Linux device driver area.

Comment: Existing implementations question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175960/which-drivers-are-used-by-usb-mouse-in-linux-kernel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As guidance given by Mr. Stark which is essential before writing a module. As far as the problem of usb mouse driver you can check the following [link](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/330/). For the unknown USB device you can refer this [link.](http://matthias.vallentin.net/blog/2007/04/writing-a-linux-kernel-driver-for-an-unknown-usb-device/)
More links for usb mouse driver : [link1](http://www.compsoc.man.ac.uk/~moz/kernelnewbies/documents/kdoc/mousedrivers/debugging.html) [link2](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/input/input.html)

Answer (score 4):

Read [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) which tells you everything you need to know.  Linux includes a USB mouse driver (I'm using one right now) which should be a good reference.

Answer (score 4):

First, it can be useful to take a look to [Linux USB](http://www.linux-usb.org/). See [writing USB device drivers](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/writing_usb_driver.html).