# the probe function not being called?

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

I want to understand why the probe function not being called.
what do I need to study to fix the problem with any USB type to auto-detected after the insertion automatically?
I use key a keyboard, kernel 5.6.3

Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <linux/module.h>    /*included for all kernel modules*/
#include <linux/kernel.h>    /*included for KERN_DEBUG*/
#include <linux/init.h>      /*included for __init and __exit macros*/
#include <linux/usb.h>
#include <linux/usb/input.h>
#include <linux/hid.h>

#define MY_USB_VENDOR_ID 0x045e
#define MY_USB_PRODUCT_ID 0x0800
static struct usb_device_id my_usb_table[] = {
       { USB_DEVICE(MY_USB_VENDOR_ID, MY_USB_PRODUCT_ID) },
       {},
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(usb, my_usb_table);

static int
my_pdrv_probe(struct usb_interface *pdev, const struct usb_device_id *id) {
    pr_err("Hello\n");
    return 0;
}

static void my_pdrv_remove(struct usb_interface *pdev) {
    pr_err("Bye\n");
}

static struct usb_driver mypdrv = {
    .name = "my first usb driver",
    .probe = my_pdrv_probe,
    .disconnect = my_pdrv_remove,
};
// module_usb_driver(mypdrv);

static int __init my_pdev_init(void)
{
    pr_err("Hello Guy\n");
    /* Refister with kernel  */
    usb_register(&mypdrv);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit my_pdev_remove(void)
{
    pr_err("Bye Guy\n");
    /* Unregister from kernel */
    usb_deregister(&mypdrv);
}

module_init(my_pdev_init);
module_exit(my_pdev_remove);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Sohaib Mohammed");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("first usb driver module");
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");
```

Comment: You forgot to link driver to ID table. You basically have dangling ID table.

Comment: @0andriy Aha, sorry. I added it but the same (problem)[https://gist.github.com/smalinux/3d6a5b000a32b97250b2d0c86b90711b] exit.

Comment: You probably need to unbind existing driver for this device. Read also: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/BuildingKernelModules and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175960/which-drivers-are-used-by-usb-mouse-in-linux-kernel.